# SVM formulations using sedumi

Tags: matlab, svm

As I am new to Sedumi modeling framework, would like to get help in writing SVM model formulations (binary or multiclass) in Sedumi. I have tried in CVXPY which is in python, but wanted to have it in matlab.

Below is the code snippet considered in python using cvxpy:

#Objective function:

obj = Minimize(0.5*( square(norm(W[0],2)) + square(norm(W[1],2)) +square(norm(W[2],2))) + C * (sum(Psi_0) + sum(Psi_1) + sum(Psi_2)))

#Constraints:

constraints = constraints_1 + z_constraints0 + z_constraints1

#Problem optimization using cvxpy

prob = Problem(obj, constraints)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try [Cvx](https://cvxr.com). It is the inspiration for Cvxy.